# Creating a binary search tree using a while loop, doesn't store all the elements nor traverses the tree properly

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *left, *right;
} node;

node *create(int value)
{
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp -> data = value;
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

node *insert(node *root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return create(value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value < root -> data)
        {
            root -> left = insert(root -> left, value);
            return root;
        }
        else if (value > root -> data)
        {
            root -> right =  insert(root -> right, value);
            return root;
        }
    }
    return root;
}

void traverse(node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty List!\n");
    }
    if (root -> left != NULL)
    {
        traverse(root -> left);
    }
    printf("%i ", root -> data);
    if (root -> right != NULL)
    {
        traverse(root -> right);
    }
}

bool search(node* root, int value)
{
    node *temp = root;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp -> data == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (value < temp -> data)
        {
            temp = temp -> left;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp -> right;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

node* deleteNode(node* root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Tree!\n");
        return root;
    }
    if (value < root -> data)
    {
        root -> left = deleteNode(root -> left, value);
    }
    else if (value > root -> data)
    {
        root -> right = deleteNode(root -> right, value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (root -> left == NULL)
        {
            node *temp = root -> right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root -> right == NULL)
        {
            node *temp = root -> left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int main(void)
{
    node* root = NULL;
    node* nodes[] = {NULL};
    bool process;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        char input;
        printf("Enter C to create a tree, I to insert an element, S to search an element, D                     to delete an element and T to traverse the tree - ");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        if (input == 'I' || input == 'i')
        {
            int value;
            printf("Enter the data - ");
            scanf("%i", &value);
            fgetc(stdin);
            nodes[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            nodes[i] = insert(root, value);
            char p;
            printf("Enter 'y' to continue, 'n' to quit - ");
            scanf("%c", &p);
            fgetc(stdin);
            if (p == 'y' || p == 'Y')
            {
                process = true;
            }
            else if (p == 'n' || p == 'N')
            {
                process = false;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid input, exiting\n");
                process = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        else if (input == 'C' || input == 'c')
        {
            int value;
            printf("Enter the data - ");
            scanf("%i", &value);
            fgetc(stdin);
            root = insert(root, value);
            char p;
            printf("Enter 'y' to continue, 'n' to quit - ");
            scanf("%c", &p);
            fgetc(stdin);
            if (p == 'y' || p == 'Y')
            {
                process = true;
            }
            else if (p == 'n' || p == 'N')
            {
                process = false;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid input, exiting\n");
                process = false;
            }
        }
        else if (input == 'D' || input == 'd')
        {
            int value;
            printf("Enter the data - ");
            scanf("%i", &value);
            fgetc(stdin);
            deleteNode(root, value);
            char p;
            printf("Enter 'y' to continue, 'n' to quit - ");
            scanf("%c", &p);
            fgetc(stdin);
            if (p == 'y' || p == 'Y')
            {
                process = true;
            }
            else if (p == 'n' || p == 'N')
            {
                process = false;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid input, exiting\n");
                process = false;
            }
        }
        else if (input == 'S' || input == 's')
        {
            int value;
            printf("Enter value - ");
            scanf("%i", &value);
            fgetc(stdin);
            if (search(root, value))
            {
                printf("Found\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not Found\n");
            }
            char p;
            printf("Enter 'y' to continue, 'n' to quit - ");
            scanf("%c", &p);
            fgetc(stdin);
            if (p == 'y' || p == 'Y')
            {
                process = true;
            }
            else if (p == 'n' || p == 'N')
            {
                process = false;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid input, exiting\n");
                process = false;
            }
        }
        else if (input == 'T' || input == 't')
        {
            traverse(root);
            char p;
            printf("Enter 'y' to continue, 'n' to quit - ");
            scanf("%c", &p);
            fgetc(stdin);
            if (p == 'y' || p == 'Y')
            {
                process = true;
            }
            else if (p == 'n' || p == 'N')
            {
                process = false;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid input, exiting\n");
                process = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        }
    }
    while (process);
}
```

I want to create a binary search tree which takes input from the user, so i put the a while loop inside the main function which runs as long as the bool variable "process" is true.

it compiles ok, no function gives any seg fault or any error of other kind. But the search function works only on the last two elements i inserted, the traverse function only prints out the last two elements along with 0. I don't know what's worng with my code...

Comment: In your typedef, you should be using a name other than `node`.  You're already using that name to declare the `struct`.

Comment: Or, just change the first `node` to something else, like `struct nodeStruct`.

Comment: The `nodes` array in `main` is only one element long, so only `nodes[0]` can be used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is a good idea to introduce alias node for the struct node.

Comment: I'm not clear what the `'I'` (or `'i'`) handling path is for, since the `'C'` (or `'c'`) handling path looks like it already supports inserting items in the tree.

Comment: @RobertHarvey did that, it didn't change anything!

Comment: @IanAbbott Providing a size for the array worked! Thanks,

Comment: @IanAbbott but how can i make the tree more dynamic, any suggestions?